# Packer Docker builder with nginx as base image

Tags: docker, nginx, packer

Expecting

```
Here is my packer file:

{
        "builders" : [
        {
                "type": "docker",
                "image": "nginx",
                "commit": "true"
        }
        ],
        "provisioners" : [
        {
                "type": "file",
                "source": "./index.html",
                "destination": "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"
        }
        ],
        "post-processors" : [
        {
                "type": "docker-tag",
                "repository": "repo",
                "tag": "latest"
        }
        ]
}
```

After **packer build** for above file when running the docker container out of the above outputted artifact i.e. custom nginx docker image with command **docker run -it -d -p 8080:80 --name web repo**, observed that the docker container comes up, port is occupied but nginx process isn't running inside the docker container due to which html content is not accessible on the specified port.
URL: http://localhost:8080

However, the above scenario of creating custom nginx docker image and running docker container for the same is performed using below Dockerfile with docker commands it works fine i.e. docker container comes up, port is occupied and also HTML content is accessible:

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

I need to use packer docker builder, what can be the possible problem? Are there any limitations on usage of docker builder with packer or with nginx?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that packer in all its glory overwrites the entrypoint. Packer works by "execing" into a running container and committing it. So it doesn't use the docker build system, actually.

When you commit the container, the image will get the entrypoint and cmd with what the container was started, in case of packer it sets the entrypoint to`/bin/sh` by default.

One option would be to not let it change the entrypoint. I have removed `--entrypoint` from the default command.

```sh
source "docker" "nginx" {
  image  = "nginx"
  commit = true
  run_command = ["-d", "-i", "-t", "--", "{{.Image}}"]
}
```

However, I am not sure if this always works. I think nginx entrypoint is special because it will just execute the arguments at the end and if nginx wasn't the first argument, it does nothing else.

```sh
exec "$@"
```

Maybe sometimes you need to give it a shell entrypoint in order to get packer working properly in the image. Afterwards, restore the cmd and entrypoint in the changes array. Strange enough, when I am doing this, I need to restore the `CMD` as well as it otherwise will be `null`.

```sh
source "docker" "nginx" {
  image  = "nginx"
  commit = true
  changes = [
    "ENTRYPOINT [\"/docker-entrypoint.sh\"]",
    "CMD [\"nginx\", \"-g\", \"daemon off;\"]"
  ]
}
```

Here is a full working example

```sh
packer {
  required_plugins {
    docker = {
      version = ">= 1"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/docker"
    }
  }
}
source "docker" "nginx" {
  image  = "nginx"
  commit = true
  # either don't overwrite the entrypoint
  run_command = ["-d", "-i", "-t", "--", "{{.Image}}"]
  # or restore it
  changes = [
    "ENTRYPOINT [\"/docker-entrypoint.sh\"]",
    "CMD [\"nginx\", \"-g\", \"daemon off;\"]"
  ]
}
build {
  sources = [
    "source.docker.nginx",
  ]
  provisioner "file" {
    source = "./index.html"
    destination = "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"
  }
  post-processor "docker-tag" {
    repository = "web"
  }
}
```